# How do I add full screen iAd's on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad

When a user clicks a button, I want a full screen iAd to appear, before the user can continue.

I can create the popup view, but how do I fill the whole view with an iAd? (e.g. like its done in wordfeud)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ADInterstitialAd (or full screen iAd) is only available for the iPad. You can't use it on the iPhone.

From [iAd Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/Full-ScreenAdvertisements/Full-ScreenAdvertisements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH5-SW1):

> Full-Screen Advertisements are Only Available on **iPad**

Have a look at that guide to see how to implement full-screen iAds on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ADInterstitialAd](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iAd/Reference/ADInterstitialAd_Ref/) class. You can present it from another view controller (e.g. your main game board’s) with `-presentFromViewController:`, or within an existing view with `-presentInView:`.